# ASP.NET - The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, devexpress

I have aspxgridexporter and a button, when I click on the button it says:

> The message received from the server could not be parsed.

I could not put Trigger it gives me an error saying the trigger is not found in update panel.

this is my vb.net code and aspx code

```
Dim options As DevExpress.XtraPrinting.XlsExportOptions = New DevExpress.XtraPrinting.XlsExportOptions()
options.SheetName = "grid"
cusgrdexport.WriteXlsToResponse(options)
```

this is a part aspx code

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="print"  text="printing" OnClick="print_Click" />
<dx:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="cusgrdexport" GridViewID="dgCustomer" ExportEmptyDetailGrid="True" FileName="Customers" runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" KeyFieldName="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ID="dgCustomer" ClientInstanceName="customergrid" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Glass/{0}/styles.css" CssPostfix="Glass" Width="690px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt">
```

**I need a Solution Urgently, Please**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have Found the Answer for that

```
Dim sm As ScriptManager = CType(Page.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager1"), ScriptManager)
        sm.RegisterPostBackControl(Button)
```

This will do it

Comment: I cant accept it cause of 2 days rule. Website wont let me but it works